# How to make question mark optional in RewriteRules?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

```
www.example.com/chk-error/errcat=5&errcd=514&id=12&in=gt5
```

that I can grab using the follow RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^chk-error/(.*) chk_err.php?error=$1 [L]
```

Now I need to grab this url:

```
www.example.com/chk-error/?errcat=5&errcd=514&id=12&in=gt5
```

That is almost the same but has only the question mark "chk-error/**?**".

I would like to make it optional. I mean, I would like a RewriteRule to grab both urls with OR without **question mark**.

Answer (score 1):

Your second url contains a Querystring. To grab parts of the querystring , you need to match against %{QUERY_STRING} variable, try this rule to handle your second url

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^chk-error/$ chk-error.php?error=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Also, change your first rule's capture group **(.*)** to **(.+)** to force at least one character after the uri.